# How do I rotate an object to a specific axis?

Tags: objects, transforms, snapping

The object (the weird shape) has been rotated and I want it to line up with an axis again. Rotation in Blender doesn't snap like it does in Sketchup, so I tried snapping it to an object (the cube) which also doesn't work. What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: has it been rotated in object mode or in edit mode?

Comment: I'm not sure. How can I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snap the 3D cursor to Vertex A (Shift S > Cursor to selected). Set the pivot point as "3D Cursor" and the snap type to "Vertex".

Select the object, press R, Z, B, click on vertex B, click on vertex C.

Works only on 4.0 and above.

[image]

Comment: That actually did it! Thanks so much for the crazily detailed explanation!